# Near duplicate lines in pbxproj files, are they important?

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a project with another developer. I've just spent some time inside our project's pbxproj file to fix a git merge conflict. The conflict is fixed but I noticed that the file contains what I thought were lots of duplicate lines. For example in the section marked `/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */` I see these lines

```
5BCA43CE1BB1823D00267A32 /* LoginViewController.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 5BCA43CD1BB1823D00267A32 /* LoginViewController.swift */; };
5BCA43CF1BB1823D00267A32 /* LoginViewController.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 5BCA43CD1BB1823D00267A32 /* LoginViewController.swift */; };
```

(and many similar 'duplicate' lines). But they are not duplicates, the id at the beginning of the first has the substring "3CE" while the second reads "3CF".

What are these near duplicate lines? Are they a byproduct of git merges or a fundamental part of how Xcode's pbxproj files work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Xcode generates unique reference(ID's) for files referenced in multiple targets. 
I suppose you are having more than one build targets and LoginViewController referenced in both which ends up with different fileRef ID's.
Although it looks identical but removing them assuming that it might be harmless may cause **crashes**.

You can read more about pbxproj file from http://www.monobjc.net/xcode-project-file-format.html.